# application: not a procedure when using match in racket

Tags: racket

I was trying out match in racket, but I encountered a very strange error. Here is my simple code:

```
(match '(+ 1 1)
    [(list + a b) (+ a b)])
```

I received this error:

```
application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: '+
```

Then I tried to use `apply` like this:

```
(match '(+ 1 1)
    [(list + a b) (apply + (list a b))])
```

Still, I got the same error.

However, when I try `(+ 1 1)`, it works.

I have read several posts about this error, it seems that it is caused by parentheses. However, I don't think there is a such error in my very simple code.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it doesn't work is because you are binding `+` as a local variable.

```
(let ((match-value '(+ 1 1)))
  (if (= 3 (length match-value))
      (let ([+ (car match-value)]
            [a (cadr match-value)]
            [b (caddr match-value)])
        (+ a b))
      'undefined-value))
```

Another problem is that you are not really matching a `+`. It matches any value. You really want this:

```
(match '(+ 1 1)
  [(list '+ a b) (+ a b)]
  [_ (error "no match")])
```